# Communicating with peripherals and I/O ports from Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

Before moving towards silverlight.. I want to know if the latest version of Silverlight 5 is capable of communicating and interacting directly with I/O ports or any other USB HID devices/ peripherals?

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way you could do is to run it in a browser and use pInvoke calls.